# Query closed questions

Tags: support, closed-questions, search

Just wondering if there's a way to query all the closed questions in Stack Overflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The search operator for searching through closed questions is `closed:1`. See that, and other search operators, in the [Advanced Search Options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=), accessible also by entering a blank search.