# How do I get the list of questions that are currently "on hold"?

Tags: support, search, on-hold

Please do not mark and close this question as a duplicate of "[Query closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54753/query-closed-questions)" as the proposed duplicate does not answer the question of how to get the questions labeled [on hold] (rather than [closed]) -- as per comment posted by NormalHuman.

I would like to get ***all*** the questions that are currently put "**on hold**". These questions are labeled with **[on hold]** at the **end** of the **post title** (Please see a NOTE at the bottom).

So far I have tried the following search keywords:

- **on hold**: too general and displays over 1500+ results
- **"on hold"**: displays over 780+ results
- **[on-hold]**: displays 95 results. I was really hoping this tag would give me the expected result but it did not. It was showing all the posts that were *suggested* with "on-hold" tag while submission.

Here are few **example questions** that have **[on hold]** at the **end** of the **post title** (Please see a NOTE at the bottom): (Note: After [5 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question) these will be labeled with "[closed]")

1. [careers tools are too limited to search for candidates [on hold]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261731/careers-tools-are-too-limited-to-search-for-candidates)
2. [Why are Stack Overflow people nice? [on hold]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47698/why-are-stack-overflow-people-nice)
3. [How to avoid infinite activity crash on Android? [on hold]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261488/how-to-avoid-infinite-activity-crash-on-android)

How should I get the questions ***just*** like the above ones i.e. labeled with [on hold] in their title not mixed with anything else?

**NOTE**:
The question *title* is usually the **actual page title** (`<title>....</title>`) for most of the posts BUT in case of "on hold" (and may be "closed", "duplicate") it's not true. So, its "actual page title" vs "post title". I learned something new here. Thanks to Patrick Hofman(see comment below) for this find.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186906/advanced-search-term-for-on-hold-distinguished-from-closed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query closed questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54753/query-closed-questions)

Comment: @random The proposed duplicate does not answer the question of how to get the questions labeled [on hold] (rather than [closed]).

Comment: @random my question is about finding questions currently "[on hold]" in their title tag...

Comment: @NormalHuman Thanks but someone just marked it duplicate again with the post random pointed earlier... can u please help

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question it is not part of the title to search

Comment: You cannot search by who closed a question, even if they are moderators

Comment: @random I do not need to know "who closed the question" please click on those example links in my post to see what I mean. I need to get list of questions that are currently active with "[on hold]" label in their title.

Comment: You specifically say you want to search for those questions closed by moderators, not just closed, but by moderators

Comment: @random "on hold" is "closed"? is that because I said "on hold" by moderators? IF yes, I removed that reference now from the post

Comment: On hold is indeed closed. After two days it gets labeled differently in the UI, but in the back nothing changes. And the label is not in the actual title so you need to search for closed question that have been closed less than two days ago.

Comment: Why do you want to know? Many of them are in the reopen queue, but if they haven't been edited since they were put on hold they will not be in the queue.

Comment: Also, a dupe is not defined by *current* answers alone. If the duped question *can potentially* answers your question then it's still a dupe :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thank you. I agree that "on hold" is equivalent of "closed" BUT there is a 5 days period before it is labeled as "closed". Also, the reason I said "on hold label is in the title" because it is at the end of post title which usually is the "actual title" but apparently not in this case. So, its "actual title" vs "post title". I learned something new here.

Comment: You could use `closed:1 active:2d` for closed questions which last activity was less than two days.

Comment: @Braiam Thanks that works too but then it will give me "duplicate" and "migrated" too... I want just "[on hold]" posts. rene's answer is perfect: I searched using closed:yes created:2d duplicate:no migrated:no

Comment: Check rene's answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 3 possible ways to get that information, some are less precise than the other but each of them can be useful depending on your specific requirement or use case.

#### Search

The search capabilites of the Stack Exchange sites don't have the possiblity to search for ALL on-hold questions because the status on-hold is not differentiated from closed in the search engine.

If you are interested in the recent/new questions that are on hold you could use the search query:

[`closed:yes created:5d.. duplicate:no migrated:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+created%3A5d..+duplicate%3Ano+migrated%3Ano)

but that only works for questions asked in the last 5 days.

#### Stack API

To get the results you are after you need to leverage the [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) which I have used in the included and runnable code snippet:

```js
(function () {
  var api = {
    url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/',
    endpoint: 'search/advanced',
    params: { 
      site: 'stackoverflow',
      pagesize: 100,
      order: 'desc',
      sort: 'activity',
      closed: 'True',
      migrated: 'False',
      Filter: '!Pw)kIARMuFW9bQ0Mxv)LqDCFAFq9fY'
      }
    };
    
    
  function createUrl(ap) {
    var ep = ap.url + ap.endpoint +'?',
     nv = [];
    $.each(ap.params, function (k,v) {
       nv.push(k + '=' + v);
    });
    console.log(ep + nv.join('&'));
    return ep + nv.join('&');
  }
 
  function enableLoad(func) {
    $('#load').show();
    $('#load').one('click', func);
  }
   
  function load(page) {
    console.log(page);
    api.params.page = page;
    $('#load').hide();
    $.get(createUrl(api), function (data) {
      var i, 
          list = $('#onhold'),
          next;
      for(i = 0; i < data.items.length; i = i +1) {
        if (typeof data.items[i].closed_details !== 'undefined' &&
            data.items[i].closed_details.on_hold) {
          list.append(
            $('<div></div>').append(
            $('<a></a>')
              .attr('href', data.items[i].link)
              .html(data.items[i].title)
            ));
        }
      }
      if (data.has_more) {
        next = function () { load(page + 1); };
        if (data.backoff !== undefined) {
          window.setTimeout( function () {
              enableLoad(next);
            }, 
            data.items.backoff * 1000);  
        } else {
            enableLoad(next);
        }
      } else {
        $('#load').hide(); 
      }
    });
  }
  
  load(1);
}());
```

```css
#onhold div {
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  }

#load {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center; 
  cursor: pointer
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="error" style="display:none">
</div>
<div id="onhold">
  
</div>
<div id="load" style="display:none">
 Click to load more ...
</div>
```

This works by using the [`search/advanced`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) endpoint, iterating over the results and check if in the subtype [`closed_details`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/closed-details) the field `on_hold` is true.

In that case I add a link to the question in the result. As the results are paged you have to click *load more* to load the next batch.

#### The Stack Exchange Data Explorer

One other option that could work once a week is to query [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) just after the refresh (normally on Monday morning around 3:00 UTC). The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/342297/on-hold-question-on-refresh-of-sede) could help with that:

```sql
declare @lastupdate datetime
select @lastupdate =  create_date 
from sys.databases
where database_id = db_id()

select [postid] as [Post Link]
from posthistory
where creationdate > dateadd(d, -5, @lastupdate)
and posthistorytypeid = 10 -- close
```

At posting this query returned 3,586 rows for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This answer solves my problem. Thank you for the SEDE query.

Comment: I got perfect result by modifying your options as -  closed:yes created:2d duplicate:no migrated:no